# Edits required for on-topic help page

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm referring to this: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

1. "asking for a hardware shopping recommendation" should be included. Don't know why it is not explicitly mentioned when it's a valid off-topic close option.
2. "asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation" - Can we edit that to read "product (software)" instead? I've had an experienced and relatively high rep user argue with me that FOSS does not fall under any of the three categories and so asking for it is allowed.

Comment: Just because you're not paying for it does not mean it isn't a product and therefore bound by the same rules. Is Windows 10 not a product because millions of people will be getting it free? No, it's still a product.  I'd be tempted to make these changes simply to remove the ambiguity that exists.

Comment: @Mokubai: Of course I agree with you and that's the very same argument I put forth as well. Removal of ambiguity is precisely why I'm advocating these changes.

Answer (score 6):

1. It comes under product recommendation. It's actually been disallowed longer than software recommendations.
2. A software recommendation is a software recommendation, free, paid, or if you get paid to use it. The correct way to ask for software is to ask about a *problem*, and the software should be part of the solution, not the solution. The user in question is wrong.

That said, yeah, there's probably ambiguity, but partially in the sense that people are reading what they want to read, or not at all.

Comment: I'm advocating these edits just to remove all ambiguity. Let's not have to explain that hardware rec is also covered and so on. After all it's a separate reason for closure so why not mention it on that page as well? More clarity won't hurt, that's for sure.

Comment: heh. I'm starting to see the merits of this ;p

Comment: Let's get it done then. :) What's the procedure BTW? Can any mod do it or do you have to get the SE devs involved?

Comment: I've brought it up to the other mods. I'd *guess* it'll take a while tho. I'm not entirely sure how we go about doing it yet ;p